# Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

Admittedly a tiresome topic but i'm totally stuck:

I'm trying to set the height of an iframe to its content height using the jquery autoheight plugin (https://github.com/house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height) and jQuery v1.7.

Due to cross-domain issues i've build a (curl-)wrapper so everything is on the same domain. The html markup for the iframe looks like:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="/de/pressrelease/proxy/?uri=<my-uri>"></iframe>
```

Unfortunalty jquery spits out this error:
[Error: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument']

I've already did a lot of research and e.g. checked this question: [Permission denied to access property in IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690598/permission-denied-to-access-property-in-iframe)

Even tried to set an absolute uri in the iframe source - same error.

Response header from the parent document:

```
Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2012 09:42:11 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.18-nmm1
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3554
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

200 OK
```

Header from the curl-proxy-wrapper (iframe):

```
Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2012 09:42:07 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.18-nmm1
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4102
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

200 OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snap! Found the problem! document.domain was set to a wrong domain ...