# ColorBox - prevent closing

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I want to prevent closing the colorbox accidentally so I'll be showing/hiding the close button from inside the loaded iframe.

I read the documentation but both examples don't seem to work:

```
var originalClose = $.colorbox.close;
$.colorbox.close = function(){
    var response;
    if($('#cboxLoadedContent').find('form').length > 0){
        response = confirm('Do you want to close this window?');
        if(!response){
            return; // Do nothing.
        }
    }
    originalClose();
};
```

or

```
<!-- calling colorbox's close method from within an iframe: -->
<a href='#' onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;'>close this iframe</a>
```

... the colorbox just doesn't close. What am I doing wrong?

in the console I see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'colorbox' of undefined
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `colorbox.css` and `jquery.colorbox.js` after `jquery` library.

Your first example overrides colorbox `close` function and second example just closing colorbox.

```
$('#cboxLoadedContent').find('form')
```

In my example I don't have `form`, so I remove `form` selector.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BY3ZK/

Colorbox is just `div`, not iframe, so I remove `parent` from here:

```
parent.$.colorbox.close();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BY3ZK/1/

Comment: Thats the thing, it works normally but not from within an iframe.

Comment: @Nimbuz iframe from same domain?

Comment: No, external domain. I mean the content from a different domain is loaded into the iframe.

Comment: @Nimbuz Your code with `parent` is valid for accessing from iframe, but browser security policy was changed. I am getting this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690598/permission-denied-to-access-property-in-iframe

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
parent.$('#yourElement').colorbox.close();
```

Where *yourElement* would be the ID / Selector of the iframe containing the colorbox.

Comment: iframe containing the lightbox? Its the lightbox containing the iframe, and iframe has NO ID

Answer (score 0):

Try using $('#cboxClose').remove(); to close the colorbox

Comment: instead of adding always you might consider flagging duplicates you found.