# Firefox 19 print PDF from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf

I have a "Print" button which invokes the following JavaScript

```
window.frames.myPdfFrame.print();
```

where "myPdfFrame" refers to an iframe with a PDF for the src.

In Chrome and Firefox 18 (and below) this opens the print dialog as expected, but as of Firefox 19 I get the following error

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'
```

I assume this is related to using the [embedded PDF viewer released with Firefox 19](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/19.0/releasenotes/) rather than the Adobe plugin. Using the print icon in the toolbar of the PDF plugin works as expected.

Is there a way to invoke the print dialog on an inline PDF in Firefox 19 from Javascript?

Comment: Is this an accurate sample of what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/hytcX/3/

Comment: Yeah me too, I though a running example might help others dig into this

Comment: Yes that's a good sample, and reproduces the error.

Comment: I think it's impossible.  Everything I've found shows that you need to define a print function inside the iframe, and if you have an iframe who's src is a PDF then you don't have this option.

Comment: I think this is covered by [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792816) which [should be fixed in Firefox 21](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=839627).

Comment: @EnsignRicky that is not the related bug. That bug is about permissions within the PDF file. If you generated a PDF you can set certain permissions the get embedded within the file and Firefox's pdf.js does currently not adhere to that.

Comment: Just tried it in Firefox 21 and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Confirmed broken in FF 23 (latest beta).

Comment: Firefox 41.0.2 (ubuntu) still broken.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the provided [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hytcX/3/), with Firefox 22 **and NoScript**. Interestingly, when I first opened the fiddle, the iframe's content was blocked by NoScript, but the print dialog readily popped up! I clicked "Ok", and I got a taskbar toast saying the document *about.blank* was sent to the printer. Sure enough, I checked the printer and it spit out a nice white page. Not useful...

Now, after telling NoScript to "temporarily allow" the domain of the PDF (irs.gov), I reproduce the bug :

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'
```

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690598/permission-denied-to-access-property-in-iframe) made me wonder if it was a problem of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So I tested it on my own webserver, with a PDF document hosted on the same machine. And... no dice !

I then tried my test page in IE 9 and Chrome. Both of them *do show* the print dialog, but when I print the document, in the case of IE 9, it's actually printing about:blank, and Chrome prints a grey rectangle saying "Loading"... looks like it's printing the whole page, not just the document in the iframe.

So, I agree with Jason Sperske that this doesn't seem possible.

**UPDATE** : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2495430/2067786) offers a solution that "just works", but only for PHP files generated by the [Fpdf library](http://www.fpdf.org/)...

Comment: The Chrome "Loading..." can be fixed if you set a timeout (of an appropriate length...I don't know what); for some even listening to the onload event doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

On recent versions of Firefox (since 19), you have to disable the bugged and native PDF viewer (pdf.js) in `about:config`. Set the `pdfjs.disabled` property to `true` and you will see the print window appearing using your script.

If there's a download starting, set the `plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types` property to `application/pdf`.

Comment: Also found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769933/firefox-printing-pdf-in-an-iframe-throws-an-error

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code, it's working:

```
window.frames.myPdfFrame.focus();
window.print();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't work for me on IE 9, nor on Firefox 22.