# Firefox printing PDF in an iframe throws an error

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing

Need help

I need to load PDF into `iframe` while clicking and then call print dialog on it.

I have such code:

```
$('.print').click(function () {
   var iframe = '<iframe src="test.pdf" id="print-iframe" name="print-iframe"></iframe>';
   $('body').append(iframe);
   window.frames["print-iframe"].focus();
   window.frames["print-iframe"].print();
});
```

It works perfectly in Chrome. But in Firefox I have such an error:
`Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'`.

How can I work around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On recent versions of Firefox (since 19), you have to disable the bugged and native PDF viewer (pdf.js) in `about:config`. Set the `pdfjs.disabled` property to `true` and you will see the print window appearing using your script.

If there's a download starting, set the `plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types` property to `application/pdf`.

Comment: This worked for me, but final solution for me was to update compatability.js to newer version

Answer (score -2):

This is error of Src in iframe with full url src="domain.com/file.pdf"

you can try

```
$('.print').click(function () {

  var domain = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
  var iframe = '<iframe src="'+domain+'/test.pdf" id="print-iframe" name="print-iframe"></iframe>';
  $('body').append(iframe);
  window.frames["print-iframe"].focus();
  window.frames["print-iframe"].print();
});
```

Comment: seems no.. that bug in FF since version 19 and will be fixed in 21 - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792816, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011799/firefox-19-print-pdf-from-javascript

Comment: @Kosmetika I fear that bug is not related to this issue. It's different kinds of "permissions".

Comment: This answer shouldn't be accepted. It ends in the same error.