# Print pdf without fixing FF browser settings

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, printing

How can I force pdf to be printed at the user end?  I've pdf file and I use iframe to insert it and print out:

```
<iframe id="iFramePdf" src="/rates.pdf" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">  // print pdf in iFrame  
function printTrigger(elementId) {
    var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId);
    getMyFrame.focus();
    getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();
}
</script>
```

But because of FF browser settings it failed to print. I know of [this soltion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769933/firefox-printing-pdf-in-an-iframe-throws-an-error) to this issue and I've fixed the issue in my FF browser. But I can't fix FF settings at user browser.

**Can I bypass it somehow? How to print pdf any other way?**

### Update

The following image shows what setting I've done to make pdf to be printable in FF:

[image]

Can I make *.pdf file prinable bypassing browser settings?

Comment: "because of FF browser settings it failed to print". Can you be more specific about what settings are and how they prevent you from printing? The accepted answer to the question you link only explains how to disable the internal viewer and (I presume) assumes the user has a PDF viewer installed in his computer—but once away from the browser I can't believe you can trigger printing from a browser feature designed to print HTML.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, thanks for your comment. See my update.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, can you explain what you've written: *but once away from the browser I can't believe you can trigger printing from a browser feature designed to print HTML*

Comment: Just a guess since I haven't tried it but... If your iframe contents are handled by a browser plug-in (or, even worse, an external program), can you still make `getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();` work? That was my concern about that answer. --- I've seen your update, it's clear now: you mean disabling Firefox builtin PDF viewer.