# how to print PDF document from firefox browser using jquery\javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, pdf, iframe

I am getting permission denied for 'print' property

```
    function printTrigger(elementId) {
        var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId);
        getMyFrame.focus();
        getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough. Which data do you want to print? Just data in the frame? Or the data from server side?

Answer (score 0):

To me this question is poorly described but I will give it a shot.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit() {
    if (!window.print) {
        alert("You need NS4.x to use this print button!")
        return
    }
    window.print()
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:doit()"><img src="icon-48-print.png" border=0 align="middle">
```

If that doesnt work I would like to redirect you to a "Possible copy" of a similar post. 
[Firefox 19 print PDF from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011799/firefox-19-print-pdf-from-javascript)